# Order PFQueryTableViewController cells by calculated distance from parse data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a problem with the database created on parse. I have a table that shows me how many miles of the various local (once you download the list from DB) the problem is that I would order it for distance upward, but I do not know how to do.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {

        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(refreshTable:)
                                                 name:@"refreshTable"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)refreshTable:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // Reload the recipes
    [self loadObjects];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"refreshTable" object:nil];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    query.limit = 100;

    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;   
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *AntDef = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"AnteprimaDefault"]];

    if ([AntDef isEqualToString:@"Null"])
    {   
        PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageDefault.png"];
        thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
        thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        thumbnailImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
        thumbnailImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    }

    else
    {   
        PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"Anteprima1"];
        PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];
        thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
        thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
        thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];
    }



    Lat = [[object objectForKey:@"Latitudine"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    Long = [[object objectForKey:@"Longitudine"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    Latdouble = [Lat doubleValue];
    Longdouble = [Long doubleValue];


    NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Latdouble longitude:Longdouble], nil];

    //NSLog(@"LOCATIONS COORDINATE: %@", locations);

    CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];;
    CLLocation *nearestLoc = nil;
    CLLocationDistance nearestDis = FLT_MAX;

    for (CLLocation *location in locations) {
        CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location];

        for (CLLocation *location in locations) {
            distance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
            if (nearestDis > distance) {
                nearestLoc = location;
                nearestDis = distance;
            }
        }

        text12 = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%.1f Km", nearestDis/1000];
    }

...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using PFQueryTableViewController you can not adjust the objects loaded because `self.objects` is readonly. What you can do is make a copy and then override the `- (PFUI_NULLABLE PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(PFUI_NULLABLE NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method to return the objects in the order you want.

Easiest way to sort is using something like the follow after load completes:

Add a property to your controller of the form:

```
// Property containing my sorted objects.
@property NSMutableArray *mySortedObjects;
```

Then in your code after you load the data, add this code:

```
self.mySortedObjects=[self.objects mutableCopy];
[self.mySortedObjects sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSLog(@"Sort a = %@",[a description]);
    NSLog(@"Sort b = %@",[b description]);
    NSComparisonResult result=NSOrderedSame;

    CLLocationDistance distanceFromA = <calculate distance>
    CLLocationDistance distanceFromB = <calculate distance>

    if (distanceFromA > distanceFromB){
      result=NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else if (distanceFromA < distanceFromB){
        result=NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else{
        result=NSOrderedSame;
    }

    return result;
}];
```

You now have a sorted copy of the objects loaded.

Finally override the following method so you change the object returned for a given index path:

```
- (PFUI_NULLABLE PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(PFUI_NULLABLE NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return self.mySortedObjects[indexPath.row];
  }
```

NB: This assumes all rows in the same section.

Comment: "<create from loaded data>" would be the array that is created by downloading the data? and "<calculate distance>" What did you mean? I read the coordinates by Parse. I might have a more practical example?

Comment: Correct. Download your data and create an array where each entry is for a different cell. Then sort that array as shown using distance to decide the sort order. Then reload the table. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, use `indexPath.row` to find the data for the cell being requested. Use the array size to return the number of rows for the section when requested.

Comment: Any exaple detailed with my data??

Comment: Its not clear how your data works as you do not seem to use indexPath in your code example. If you are using a table view the assumption is you have a number of sections and a number of rows per section. So you have to structure your data as sections and rows. Then use indexPath in cellForRowAtIndexPath to create and populate the appropriate cell. If you wanted sorted data, you sort the data model then reload the table.

Comment: I use PFQueryTableView

Comment: Sorry, did not spot that the end of the cellForRow... call was not the normal one. Have edited my answer with a proposed solution for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was away on business and I came back now ... I try and tell you if I work. The only thing I did not understand is that I have to put values here: **CLLocationDistance distanceFromA = <calculate distance>** - **CLLocationDistance distanceFromB = <calculate distance>**

Comment: You said you wanted to sort by distance from your location. To do that in the sort you need to know the distances. As I don't know how your code works I put in place holders. So here you need to replace whats in the <> brackets with code which calculates the distance of A and B from the location. The sort works by asking you to keep comparing nodes and you return which order they are in: ascending or descending  or the same.

Comment: On the Parse DB I've the coordinates of the shops, then how should I do?

Comment: You seem to have the code already in your question: For each object: `[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Latdouble longitude:Longdouble]` seems to give you their location. Current location is: `CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];` and the distance between them is `[currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location]`. Do that for object A and object B in the sort block.

Comment: Return error "- (PFUI_NULLABLE PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(PFUI_NULLABLE NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return self.mySortedObjects[indexPath.row];
  }" can you add you're code in my code?